# Is "paywall" suitable for an offline event?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

I learned that

> A paywall is a method of restricting access to content

And after reading the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paywall) I thought the *content* implies only digital content, like journals and news. It also appears in describing online events like [live streaming](https://bambuser.com/docs/integrations/paywall-memberful-stripe-wordpress/).

But I wonder if it can be utilized in the following scenario:

A guy in a chat room posted an offline event but didn't mention whether it is *paywalled* or not. The moment I wanted to ask I thought I should rephrase the question to sound more grammatical, then I asked: should we pay for that?

I wonder if I can ask: is it paywalled? Or is it a paywalled event? By the way, could you please recommend some native expressions to me?

Comment: The full OED defines **paywall** as *A **feature on a website** which makes certain pages or content accessible only to visitors who pay a fee* (first recorded use, 2004). You'd be understood if you used it for something *not* on the Internet, just as I didn't have much trouble understanding what an "offline" event might mean in your question text. Note that whereas for an online context you might ask whether it's ***paywalled / behind a paywall*** or not, for a real-world event we usually come at it from the opposite direction and ask whether it's ***free*** or not.

Comment: FumbleFingers, that’s a perfectly good answer; why not just post is as such, instead of as a comment?